# Operating on wildcard input files and saving output as <input> + suffix

Tags: linux, command-line, fedora, imagemagick, fedora-21

I want to batch process my a list of wildcard input files and then output then to the input filename with a suffix appended.  I'm hoping to understand this general case.

In particular, I'm running

```
    convert *.jpg -resize 800x600 ... *-resized.jpeg
```

Under Fedora21 with ImageMagick 6.6.8 is nice in that it appends a number suffix but I am looking to preserve the original filename and add a suffix.  i.e. It outputs *-resized-0.jpeg *-resized-1.jpeg ...

Checked this does not appear applicable, 
[Multiple input files and output files in awk](https://superuser.com/questions/905927/multiple-input-files-and-output-files-in-awk)

**edit:** Is this possible or do I need to write a script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how you define the word "script".  Arguably, this is a script:

```
for f in *.jpg
do
    convert "$f" -resize 800x600 ... "${f%.*}"-resized.jpeg
done
```

but you can just type it like that into your terminal. 
The command (or any number of commands) between the `do` and the `done`
get(s) executed once for each file that matches `*.jpg`,
with `$f` set to each filename. 
`${f%.*}` is a form of parameter expansion that removes the filename extension
(string matching `.*`) from the end (i.e., the right side) of the `$f` filename.

Naming the output files `.jpeg` instead of `.jpg` is a good idea,
to prevent the `*.jpg` wildcard from matching them. 
Another approach is to write the output files to a different directory.

Comment: If anyone reading this wants to do this with a one liner solution, just add semi-columns like so : 

```for f in *.jpg; do convert "$f" -resize 800x600 ... "${f%.*}"-resized.jpeg; done```